Plotting a hysteresis curve
I need to plot a hysteresis curve with given values of B and H, but, obviously it won't and definitely shouldn't give a nice straight line. My question is, considering my very beginner skills in python, is there a way I can place all my data onto a graph and connect them with a curve that looks like a hysteresis curve?
This is my code so far
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Section 1: Calculating values of H for toroid A

# defining the values to find H for toroid A
N_1 = 3420
L_1 = 0.076
R_1 = 8

# defining function to find the value of H with given V_1
def H_toroid_A(V_1):
    return (V_1 * N_1) / (L_1 * R_1)

# Section 2: Calculating the delta list of uncertainties for H toroid A

# defining variables and uncertainties
V_1_values = [3, 8, 1, 10, 5]
delta_V_1_values = [0.1, 0.2, 0.05, 0.3, 0.15]  # uncertainties for V_1
delta_N_1 = 0  # uncertainty for N_1
delta_L_1 = 0.001  # uncertainty for L_1
delta_R_1 = 0.4  # uncertainty for R_1

# function to calculate uncertainties in H
def calculate_uncertainty_H(V_values, delta_V_values, delta_N, delta_L, delta_R):
    uncertainties = []
    for i in range(len(V_values)):
        uncertainty_H = np.sqrt(
            ((V_values[i] / (L_1 * R_1)) * delta_N)**2 +
            ((N_1 / (L_1 * R_1)) * delta_V_values[i])**2 +
            ((-V_values[i] * N_1 / (L_1**2 * R_1)) * delta_L)**2 +
            ((-V_values[i] * N_1 / (L_1 * R_1**2)) * delta_R)**2
        )
        uncertainties.append(uncertainty_H)
    return uncertainties

uncertainties_H = calculate_uncertainty_H(V_1_values, delta_V_1_values, delta_N_1, delta_L_1, delta_R_1)

# Section 3: Calculating values of B for toroid A

# defining the values to find B for toroid A
R_2 = 270000
C = 220e-9
N_2 = 820
A_2 = 9.025e-5

# defining function to find the value of B with given V_c
def B_toroid_A(V_c):
    return (R_2 * C * V_c) / (N_2 * A_2)

# Section 4: Calculating list of uncertainties for B toroid A

# defining variables and uncertainties
V_c_values = [3, 8, 1, 10, 5]
delta_V_c_values = [0.1, 0.2, 0.05, 0.3, 0.15]  # uncertainties for V_c
delta_N_2 = 0  # uncertainty for N_2
delta_C = 1.1e-8  # uncertainty for C
delta_A_2 = 5e-8  # uncertainty for A_2
delta_R_2 = 13500  # uncertainty for R_2

# function to calculate uncertainties in B
def calculate_uncertainty_B(V_values, delta_V_values, delta_N, delta_C, delta_A, delta_R):
    uncertainties = []
    for i in range(len(V_values)):
        uncertainty_B = np.sqrt(
            ((C * V_values[i]) / (N_2 * A_2))**2 * delta_R_2**2 +
            ((R_2 * V_values[i]) / (N_2 * A_2))**2 * delta_C**2 +
            ((R_2 * C) / (N_2 * A_2))**2 * delta_V_values[i]**2 +
            ((R_2 * C * V_values[i]) / (N_2 * A_2**2))**2 * delta_A_2**2 +
            ((R_2 * C * V_values[i]) / (N_2**2 * A_2))**2 * delta_N_2**2
        )
        uncertainties.append(uncertainty_B)
    return uncertainties

uncertainties_B = calculate_uncertainty_B(V_c_values, delta_V_c_values, delta_N_2, delta_C, delta_A_2, delta_R_2)

# Section Alpha: calculating list of values of H
H_values = [H_toroid_A(V_1) for V_1 in V_1_values]

# Section Beta: calculating list of values of B
B_values = [B_toroid_A(V_c) for V_c in V_c_values]

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.errorbar(H_values, B_values, xerr=uncertainties_H, yerr=uncertainties_B, fmt='o')
plt.xlabel('H (Intensité du champ magnétique)')
plt.ylabel('B (Densité du flux magnétique)')
plt.title('Courbe Hysteresis')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


Right now, from what I can find, most of hysteresis curve in python suggestions are REALLY complicated and doesn't suit the data I have, because I'm not starting from scratch, I have given values that should connect together to form the appropriate curve. THE DATA RIGHT NOW IS A PLACE HOLDER, it's normal that it gives a linear curve.
I suppose it isn't much help without the actual data, but I don't have access to it at the moment.

a hysteresis curve should follow the trend and fall with it eventually. I would not expect that using plt.plot will cause a line to have zigzags. Can you provide the data whenever you can. Also. check this out: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/35482
